# How can we re-write the same code as per Zoho deluge?

Tags: javascript, zoho, zoho-deluge

I need some help in re-formatting the JS script to Zoho Deluge script.
This API sends whatsapp template message.
I was able to parse headers but not custom parameters.

```js
const options = {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json-patch+json',
    Authorization: 'Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJqdGkiOiI1ZDE1YTlkNi05MDQ2LTQ3OGMtYTk1MS0zNTA0ZDFlMGVkOGEiLCJ1bmlxdWVfbmFtZSI6InZpbGFrc2hhbkBuaXZlc2hvbmxpbmUuY29tIiwibmFtZWlkIjoidmlsYWtzaGFuQG5pdmVzaG9ubGluZS5jb20iLCJlbWFpbCI6InZpbGFrc2hhbkBuaXZlc2hvbmxpbmUuY29tIiwiYXV0aF90aW1lIjoiMDIvMjEvMjAyMiAxNjo0MjozOSIsImRiX25hbWUiOiI3MzU0IiwiaHR0cDovL3NjaGVtYXMubWljcm9zb2Z0LmNvbS93cy8yMDA4LzA2L2lkZW50aXR5L2NsYWltcy9yb2xlIjoiQURNSU5JU1RSQVRPUiIsImV4cCI6MjUzNDAyMzAwODAwLCJpc3MiOiJDbGFyZV9BSSIsImF1ZCI6IkNsYXJlX0FJIn0.f1eGyiKdnj9xj48e8WUnLzTD6UGmztJGu7HrKH886og'
  },
  body: '{"receivers":[{"customParams":[{"name":"1","value":"Missed"},{"name":"2","value":"IVR"},{"name":"3","value":"09910076952"},{"name":"4","value":"MFP1320"},{}],"whatsappNumber":"919910076952"}],"template_name":"ivr_lead","broadcast_name":"sample"}'
};

fetch('https://live-server-7354.wati.io/api/v1/sendTemplateMessages', options)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(response => console.log(response))
  .catch(err => console.error(err));
```

Comment: Could you also post the Zoho Deluge code you have tried?

Comment: That deluge tag is for a BitTorrent client called Deluge, not the scripting language you think is.

Answer (score 1):

According to your questions, you want to do POST URL using deluge script.
Based on your current data, the script to call post url is here;

```
url_post = "https://live-server-7354.wati.io/api/v1/sendTemplateMessages";
content_type = "application/json-patch+json";
authorization = "Bearer eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJqdGkiOiI1ZDE1YTlkNi05MDQ2LTQ3OGMtYTk1MS0zNTA0ZDFlMGVkOGEiLCJ1bmlxdWVfbmFtZSI6InZpbGFrc2hhbkBuaXZlc2hvbmxpbmUuY29tIiwibmFtZWlkIjoidmlsYWtzaGFuQG5pdmVzaG9ubGluZS5jb20iLCJlbWFpbCI6InZpbGFrc2hhbkBuaXZlc2hvbmxpbmUuY29tIiwiYXV0aF90aW1lIjoiMDIvMjEvMjAyMiAxNjo0MjozOSIsImRiX25hbWUiOiI3MzU0IiwiaHR0cDovL3NjaGVtYXMubWljcm9zb2Z0LmNvbS93cy8yMDA4LzA2L2lkZW50aXR5L2NsYWltcy9yb2xlIjoiQURNSU5JU1RSQVRPUiIsImV4cCI6MjUzNDAyMzAwODAwLCJpc3MiOiJDbGFyZV9BSSIsImF1ZCI6IkNsYXJlX0FJIn0.f1eGyiKdnj9xj48e8WUnLzTD6UGmztJGu7HrKH886og";

parameters_value = '{"receivers":[{"customParams":[{"name":"1","value":"Missed"},{"name":"2","value":"IVR"},{"name":"3","value":"09910076952"},{"name":"4","value":"MFP1320"},{}],"whatsappNumber":"919910076952"}],"template_name":"ivr_lead","broadcast_name":"sample"}';
parameters_value_map = parameters_value.toJSONList().toMap();
headers_value = Map();
headers_value.put("Content-Type",content_type);
headers_value.put("Authorization",authorization);
response_data =  invokeUrl
[
    url: url_post
    type: POST
    headers: headers_value
    parameters:parameters_value_map

];
info response_data;
```

Please refer to this  article for much details https://www.zoho.com/deluge/help/webhook/invokeurl-api-task.html

Thanks,
Von

Comment: Dear OP, please Don't these thankful messages.

Comment: Okay,,,,,,,,,,,